# Replace a python string using format function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string which gets replaced in the backend code. `${}` indicates that the string pattern is to be replaced. Example -

> I am going to `${location}` for `${days}`

I have a dict with values to be replaced below. I want to find if `${location}` is present in the text and replace it with the key value in `str_replacements`. Below is my code. The string replacement does not work using `.format`. It works using `%s` but i do not want to use it.

```
text = "I am going to ${location} for ${days}"
str_replacements = {
    'location': 'earth',
    'days': 100,
    'vehicle': 'car',
}

for key, val in str_replacements.iteritems():
    str_to_replace = '${{}}'.format(key)
    # str_to_replace returned is ${}. I want the key to be present here.
    # For instance the value of str_to_replace needs to be ${location} so
    # that i can replace it in the text
    if str_to_replace in text:
        text = text.replace(str_to_replace, val)
```

I do not want to use `%s` to substitute the string. I want to achieve the functionality with `.format` function.

Comment: Can you control the format on the backend? Do you need the `$`s? Why not just directly use the format that `.format` expects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an extra `{}`

**Ex:**

```
text = "I am going to ${location} for ${days}"
str_replacements = {
    'location': 'earth',
    'days': 100,
    'vehicle': 'car',
}

for key, val in str_replacements.items():
    str_to_replace = '${{{}}}'.format(key)
    if str_to_replace in text:
        text = text.replace(str_to_replace, str(val))
print(text)
#  -> I am going to earth for 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small regular expression instead:

```
import re

text = "I am going to ${location} for ${days} ${leave_me_alone}"
str_replacements = {
    'location': 'earth',
    'days': 100,
    'vehicle': 'car',
}

rx = re.compile(r'\$\{([^{}]+)\}')

text = rx.sub(lambda m: str(str_replacements.get(m.group(1), m.group(0))), text)
print(text)
```

This would yield

```
I am going to earth for 100 ${leave_me_alone}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Parameterised - Order of parameters is not followed strictly
2. Non Parametrised - Order of parameters is not followed strictly

Example as follows:

[image]